# Discord.js execute function when replying with emoji

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Currently, I am using Discord.js to make a bot.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content === '$wa') {
  message.channel.send({ embed: exampleEmbed }).then((embedMessage) => {
   embedMessage.react('❤️');

   embedMessage
    .awaitReactions(
     (filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return reaction.emoji.name === '❤️' && user.id === message.author.id;
     }),
     { max: 2, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] }
    )
    .then((collected) => {
     const reaction = collected.first();

     if (reaction.emoji.name === '❤️') {
      message.channel.send(
       ':sparkling_heart: **Hanno** and **Roronoa Zoro** are now married! :sparkling_heart:'
      );
     }
    });
  });
 }
});
```

If I type `$wa` the bot shows some embed. But the thing is that it automatically adds a heart to the embed. I want that if I click the heart as well (for a total count of 2 hearts) it executes the if statement at the bottom.

I've tried multiple methods but none worked. This is also my first time with `Discord.js`

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for the bots own reaction. I recommend redoing your `filter` implementation to something like this.
The key takeaway is that you have to add `!user.bot` to the filter so that the bot's own reaction is ignored

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
   return reaction.emoji.name === "❤️" && user.id === message.author.id && !user.bot
}

embedMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {

    if (message.content === '$wa') {
        message.channel.send({ embed: exampleEmbed }).then(embedMessage => {
            embedMessage.react('❤️');

            embedMessage.awaitReactions(filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return reaction.emoji.name === '❤️' && user.id === message.author.id;
            },
                { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] }).then(collected => {
                    const reaction = collected.first();

                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '❤️') {
                        message.channel.send(':sparkling_heart: **Hanno** and **Roronoa Zoro** are now married! :sparkling_heart:');
                    }

                }).catch(() => {
                    // user didn't react with ❤️ in given time (here: 60 secs)
                    message.channel.send('no reaction in time');
                });
        });
    }
});
```

I changed the `max` value to 1 and also added a catch block to catch a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. If you don't do so in the future, it might exit the program with an error. You can of course execute whatever you like when the user didn't react to the embedMessage in time.